# Return every row that contains the most occurring value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This question may seem similar to a common question that asks to return the most occurring value. However, I need to list every row containing the value that occurs most often.

In my example there is a zipCode that appears 3 times (the most out of any zip code). I would like to list every occurrence of that zip code without having to know which zip code has the most occurrences at the time of the query.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT *, COUNT(zipCode) AS NumOccurrences
FROM customers
GROUP BY zipCode
ORDER BY NumOccurrences DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Returns:**

[image]

**What I want to return:**

[image]

**Without using this query obviously:**

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE zipCode = 10001
```

I want to return each of the 3 occurrences of that zip code and not just the first instance of it. Without having to use the query above because I may not now which zip code occurs the most at the time of the query.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: @Nick the version is 10.1.44

Comment: In that case the window function solutions won't work as they were only introduced in version 10.2. But @eshirvana first answer should work?

Comment: @Nick When I run eshirvana's answer I get the following error:
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate to @eshirvana which might work. Again, doesn't properly account for the possibility of multiple equivalent maximums (multiple zip codes being present the same number of maximum times).

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE zipCode = (
    SELECT zipCode
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY zipCode
    ORDER BY count(zipCode) DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need to do,remember if you have tie , it randomly choose first set of zipcodes :

```
select *
FROM customers
WHERE zipCode IN (
              select zipCode 
              from customers 
              group by zipCode 
              order by count(*) desc
              limit 1
             )
```

or

```
select *
from ( 
      select * , count(*) over (partition by zipcode) rn
     )
order by rn desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
 customers.id
 , customers.city
 , customers.state
 , customers.zipCode
 , customers.firstName
 , customers.lastName
 , customers.streetAddress
from customers
join (
  select 
    x.zipAddress
    , rank() over( order by x.frequency desc ) -- the highest number will get rank #1
      as zipRank
  from (
    select c.zipAddress, count(*) as frequency 
    from customers c 
    group by c.zipAddress 
  ) x
) zip
on zip.zipAddress = customers.zipAddress
  and zip.zipRank = 1
```

Please note: if several different ZIP codes happen to have the same count in `customers` table, all of them will get rank #1 and, consequently, all the addresses containing those ZIP codes will be listed.
This will work in Oracle. I don't have an instance of MySQL nearby, but if it is version 8 or higher, it should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all zip codes with three occurrences, using window functions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             COUNT(zipCode) OVER (PARTITION BY zipCode)AS NumOccurrences
      FROM customers c
     ) c
WHERE NumOccurrences = 3
ORDER BY zipCode;
```

If you don't want to specify the "3" but want the maximum, use `RANK()` as well:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NumOccurrences DESC) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT c.*,
                   COUNT(zipCode) OVER (PARTITION BY zipCode)AS NumOccurrences
            FROM customers c
           ) c
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY zipCode;
```

Comment: I believe this might work, however it throws errors in mariaDB. I thought my University was using mysql, but it turns out they are using mariaDB since oracle acquired mysql.